# How to use drupal_write_record for updating a custom table?

Tags: 7, database

I am using the following code to add rows to a custom table used from the module I created.

```
$my_query = db_query("SELECT to_date FROM table_name where to_date = '$to'");
$num_of_results_service = $my_query->rowCount();
if ($num_of_results_service == 0) {
  try {
    $result1 = drupal_write_record('table_name', $value_array[$proj_title]);
    drupal_set_message('data saved successfully.');
  }
  catch(Exception $e) {
    echo 'Message: ' .$e->getMessage();
  }
}
else{
  // Code to update the table. 
}
```

How can I update a row of that database table?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in a 3rd parameter if you want to update the record:
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_write_record/7.x

So thats a $primary_keys array with the column names in your table you want it to match against so in your case you might need to pass "to_date" which would update all rows that have the same $to value you're using

Answer (score 0):

I used db_update although it is bit lengthy and it solved my problem. The code is as follows,

```
$entry = db_update('table_name')
  ->fields(array(
  'column_name' => $variable1,
  'column_name2' => $variable2,
  ))
  ->condition('column_name', $variable, '=')
  ->condition('to_date', $newDate, '=')
  ->execute();
drupal_set_message('Data updated successfully.');
```

It worked and I Hope this helps someone.